# Kohana database config writter

Tags: database, kohana, config

I have no clue why but the database config writter doesn't seem to work.

I've already enabled the database module and attached the driver in boostrap.php:

```
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_File);
Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_Database, FALSE);
```

When i call the writter

```
Kohana::$config->write('group', 'key', 'value');
```

it just throws an ugly exception:

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Config::write()
```

I've created the database table and **loading config works fine** when I manually insert data into the database.

note: I'm using kohana 3.2.2 with the built in database module.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the exception is thrown because of `Config_File`, which is a reader and not a writer (see http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Config_File).

Try removing `Kohana::$config->attach(new Config_File);` in your bootstrap.

Comment: but I need the file reader as well... and the wiki says that's the correct way

Comment: Hum, sorry about that, I misunderstood the user guide. So actually, class `Config` does not have a method `write`. There's a method `_write_config` (http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Config) that does the job, but I'm not sure you're supposed to call it directly (at least, it should work)

Comment: ... So instead of calling `Kohana::$config->write`, try `Kohana::$config->_write_config`